# How to keep all rows in the DOM in case of datatable pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, datatables

I have a datatable with average number of rows being 100. I have set page size as 10 rows. Everything is working but at any point of time the `<tbody>` contains only 10 `<tr>` tags. I am in a situation where we need all the 100 rows to be in the DOM. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Instead of controlling how many are added to the dom you can use either javascript or some fancy CSS to toggle the display value of all the elements that should be hidden.

Comment: Why do you need them in the DOM? You can easily access the hidden nodes through the API. @SimonHyll, No, because it is dataTables itself that hide and show the DOM nodes.

Comment: Where did you set the page size to 10 rows. Is it a framework or some library you are using..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method to access all `tr` elements. For example,

```
$('#example').DataTable()
   .$('tr')
   .addClass('important');
```

Use delegated event handlers to handle events from `tr` element that are not present in DOM. For example:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function(){
   // ... skipped ...
});
```